# i cant connect db with sqljocky

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-io

i have some problems about sqljocky/dart

```dart
var pool = new ConnectionPool(host: 'example.com', port: 3306, user: 'hvuo',
                    password: 'xxx', db: 'xxx', max: 1);
querySelector("#err1").text="Conexxon abierta";
pool.prepare("insert into ovnis (latitud,longitud,calle) values (?,?,?)").then((query){
  querySelector("#err2").text="todo casi preparado";
  query.execute([latitud,longitud,"facultad"]).then((result){
    querySelector("#err3").text=result.insertId;
  });
});
```

I have this dart code to register a simple database, but this dont insert .
what's worng?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlJocky doesn't run in the browser, only on the server.

`querySelector` is client code therefore I assume you try to run in in the browser.
You should have got an error message telling you that `dart:io` can't be used on the client (or similar).